# Low poly and normal map

Tags: normals

I just made a character and it has about ten thousands of vertices.

So, I thought I might as well low poly it and make a normal map.

1. How do I do that?
2. Do I texture paint it first? then low poly it and bake normal map? or is it the opposite?

Comment: http://blender.stackexchange.com/search?q=high+poly+low+poly+normal

Comment: You can create a low poly from the high poly using retopology tools like Retopoflow (paid add-on) or search for a retopology tutorial. 

You would create a low poly first, bake normal map, then paint a diffuse map. You could paint the diffuse map before baking the normals either way works. I would recommend creating the low poly first because you will need uvs to bake the maps and have something to paint the texture on.

Comment: As I have seen from tutorial videos, these guys first sculpt the mesh extremely fine, then they used to decimate the mesh as they make it low poly and bake normals.